# Embedding a PDF in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to embed a PDF and make it scrollable in Firefox (bonus points for the ability to zoom in/out, but right now I'd just be happy with a simple functional solution).

Basically my code is as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid align-center">
<div class="span12">
    <iframe style="float:none;display:inline;height:90%;" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span11">
        <button onclick = "history.go(-1);" class="pull-right btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go Back</button>
    </div>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

However, I noticed on Firefox that it simply prompts me to download the PDF file rather than embed it. Meanwhile, my users say it embeds in their browser, but it's sized very small.

How do I make it embed full-screen in Firefox?

On Safari/Chrome, it's fine. On iPad it only shows the first page of the PDF and it's not full-screen.

[image]

Comment: What does `{{url}}` output?

Comment: The full path to a URL that links to a PDF file.

Comment: Acrobat itself should manage this, if the user has it set up, a PDF will always open in the browser rather than download

Comment: Looks like you're using Bootstrap so I'd suggest having a div around the iframe with a span12 class on it. I don't think you'll need the span12 class on the iframe. maybe a width:100%. Also I don;t think you'll need the flat or display properties on the iframe unless those are overriding previously set properties on iframes. Lastly I don;t think that height:90% will do much unless you have a specific height set on the parent.

Comment: I believe Andy has it right, this isn't behavior you can code, it's handled by the acrobat browser plugins

Comment: Still having the problem -- I updated my code snipped to show the entire body of the page and put the span12 in a div around the iFrame -- but no luck. I also posted a screenshot of what it looks like.

Comment: I think you should try http://pdfobject.com/.

Comment: Update: Adding an absolute height on the iFrame Ex: `900px` rather than `90%` seems to solve the problem -- why is this??

Comment: @user1328021 It might be because the height of the iframe is computed before the content is populated. So it seems that it would be best to define the width and height with actual values instead of percentages.

Comment: Ok thanks. I made my height 1200px to account for some people possibly having 24 inch monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was that I added a height parameters in absolute pixels, rather than a percentage.

```
<div class="row-fluid align-center">
    <iframe class = "span12" style="float:none;display:inline;height:1200px;" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <br>
</div>
```